# logs not printing in console nor writing in log file in logging

Tags: python, logging

I have a file named `helper.py`

```
import logging
import os
from json import load

def get_config(value):
    with open('config.json','r') as f:
        result=load(f)[value]
    return result


def get_logger(name,level):
    logpath=get_config("log_path")
    if not os.path.exists(logpath):
        os.mkdir(logpath)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if not bool(logger.handlers):
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        fh = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(logpath,f'{get_config("log_file_name")}.log'),mode="w",encoding='utf-8')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        ch.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(ch)
    return logger


LOGGER=get_logger("MyLogger",logging.INFO)
```

This is `config.json`:

```
{
    "save_path" : "results/",
    "log_path" : "logs/",
    "log_file_name" : "MyLog"
}
```

let's say I am using `LOGGER` from `helper` it in `x.py`

```
from helper import LOGGER

logger=LOGGER

def div(x,y):
    try:
        logger.info("inside div")
        return x/y
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"div failed due to {e.message if 'message' in dir(e) else e}")
```

I am using this LOGGER in other files by importing `helper.LOGGER` for logging purposes but it's not printing anything on the console nor writing in a log file

**My attempt:**

- I tried adding `sys.stdout` in `StreamHandler()` It doesn't worked
- Then I tried setting the level of fh but nothing works
- I tried adding `basicConfig()` instead of `fileHandler()` but then printing to console using `print()` and the output of logs is not coming in the correct order

Kindly let me know where I go wrong

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks :)

Comment: are you missing the extension  in file name ?->`logpath = get_config('log_path.log')`

Comment: @UtpalKumar No actually I am getting the name of log file from `config.json` file...updated answer to avoid confusion kindly have a look

Comment: Can you add an example line of code that creates a log that doesn't work?

Comment: @blues added a basic example kindly have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the level on the `LOGGER`, which by default is warning. This is why your info level log is not appearing. The Python documentation has a flow chart illustrating when a log will be logged: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow

The first thing it does, is that before a logger sends a log to their handlers it checks if the level is enabled *for the logger*. You should add `logger.setLevel(level)` in your `get_logger()`.